# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/net/ns/RefusePacket

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jar, c3p0

I am facing the following error.,
I am able to connect with the Db and found this error in logs, it will print following stacktrace multiple no. of times.

```
Exception in thread "Task-Thread-for-com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner@421f054f" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/net/ns/RefusePacket
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:347)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1054)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:308)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner$TaskThread.run(ThreadPerTaskAsynchronousRunner.java:255)
```

following are the jar files i am using 
ojdbc6.jar , c3p0-0.9.1.jar ,mchange-commons-java-0.2.9.jar ,hibernate-c3p0-4.1.9.final.jar

and using hibernate4 with Java 1.7.

Your kind help will be highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean with 'using'? Compiling? Or are they available at runtime? The RefusePackaget should be in ojdbc6.jar; I guess your application (web? cli?) cannot find your ojdbc6.jar.

Comment: yes the jar are present and m able to perfom all operations too... m using linux server shall i add explicitly in to classpath ?

Answer (score 1):

You miss jar (jdbc-oracle.jar) in your classpath.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjdbcoraclejar.htm

Check the file [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc101040-094982.html)

Comment: Thanks @StanislavL for your answer I added into the classpath.. and monitoring logs...